# How to use google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Straight to the question: I just want to know where we can use google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); in the script, because I always got my map on top left corner. I will use on the web, of course.

Here's my code:

```
function initialize()
{
  var mapDiv1 = document.getElementById("googleMap-1");
  var mapDiv1 = document.getElementById("googleMap-2");
  var mapProp1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.927893, 107.775163),
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv1,mapProp1);
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv2,mapProp1);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You must trigger the resize-event when you change the size of the mapDiv's or toggle their display from none to another state.  In your function you don't do it, so triggering the resize-event will have no effect there.